# Enclose quotes, parentheses, etc. in Vim

Tags: vim

I would like to make Vim behave in the following way.

When I type a `"`, `'`, `(`, `[` or `{` it should add an extra  `"`, `'`, `(`, `[` or `{` and move the cursor back one character.

So if I type `"▉` I would love to see it automagically change that into `"▉"`,
where `▉` shows position of the cursor.

Comment: Look for delimitMate or SmartInput.

Answer (score 5):

There are *many* plugins for that. Did you search [vim.org's plugin repository](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=pair&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search) before asking?

You could also do something like:

```
inoremap { {}<C-o>h
```

Comment: I actually haven't searched the repository. Thanks for pointing that out. 
inoremap { {}<C-o>i Seems more useful with h, it moves the cursor before {}.

Comment: `<C-o>i` seems weird to me. `<C-o>h` is more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

[lh-brackets](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhBrackets#The_bracketing_subsystem) provides both the insert mode mappings and the surrounding mappings. If you want to use it for a filetype that I don't work with, you may have to add your specializations -- which is meant to be easy.

Answer (score 0):

The surround plugin might work for you:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697

Comment: I'm already using the surround plugin (and it's useful) but it does not work as I described above.

Answer (score -2):

After fiddling around, I found that a plugin for such a feature would be overkill.

I've setup my vimrc as such:

```
inoremap { {}<C-o>i
```

I've also added:

```
inoremap <C-l> <C-o>A
inoremap <C-L> <C-o>A<Space>
```

So I can quickly jump outside of the parentheses and start typing again, with our without an extra space.